# Problema con command handler al instalar Telerik para Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, telerik

Cuando instalo

```
Telerik_UI_For_WinForms_2018_1_220_Dev
```

Se instala bien, pero al abrir mi proyecto que contiene forms, no puedo visualizar y me aparece el siguiente error:

> There is already a command handler for the menu command
>   '1496a755-94de-11d0-8c3f-00c04fc2aae2 : 103'.

Comment: Probaste en TODAS esas versiones de visual studio que indicas en las etiquetas? O en cuál estás probando?

Comment: estoy probando con Visual Studio 2017